# c# Silverlight - Facebook oAuth Integration error

Tags: silverlight

I am using the SDK and other tips put down. However, I am facing the issue where I am giving my Application Id in the code then run the application. It gives me error at the line of opening Login URL:

(http://www.facebook.com/dialog...
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html&display=touch)

When I manually open this, it gives "An error occurred. Please try again later." with okay button.

I am using Silverlight version 5 and developing app for windows phone 7.1

Is there any change required?

Answer (score 0):

in the redirect_uri parameter,
you have to put the page url where facebook have to redirect the user after the authentication is done,for example:
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXX&redirect_uri=http://xxxxxx.com/default.aspx%23/Rooms?&response_type=token